# Fock Space : can we also see it at a tensorial product of 1 state Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Imagine that I work with bosons.

We know that the Fock space is the direct sum of symetrised hilbert spaces of $1,2,...,N,...$ particles. I am ok with it.

I take a state $|n_1...n_N \rangle$. I work with an operator $f(a^\dagger_{i}, a_{i})$, thus it will only act on the state $i$.

So for example $a_i |n_1...n_i...n_N \rangle=|n_1...(n_i-1)...n_N \rangle$.

**So everything is like** we had a tensorial product of hilbert space $H_i$ and if $|n_i \rangle$ is a vector of $H_i$ it means that I have $n_i$ particles in the state $|i\rangle$.

Thus my question is : can we **also** see the Fock space as a tensorial product of Hilbert space $H_0 \otimes ... \otimes H_N\otimes...$ where $H_i$ is the vector space of particles in the state $i$ (and $|n_i>$ is the basis of it).